# Calculate all possible factors of a prime

Tags: python, primes

Was going through a Python Tutorial and came across an example to check whether a number is prime or not. I changed a few things so that the result would display a list of all possible factors of the number, if the number is not a prime, However, the code didn't work.

**Code:**

```
def isprime(number):
    print "Reticulating Splines..."
    fnum=[1,]
    notprime=0
    for p in range(2, number):
        if (number % p) == 0:
            notprime=1
            fnum.append(p)
            continue
        if notprime == 1:     
            return number, "is not a prime because of these factors", fnum  
        else:
            return True
num =int(raw_input("Enter number: "))
print isprime(num)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter number: 12
Reticulating Splines...
(12, 'is not a prime because of these factors', [1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> 
Enter number: 25
Reticulating Splines...
(25, 'is a prime number')
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Enter number: 12
Reticulating Splines...
(12, 'is not a prime because of these factors', [1, 2, 3, 4, 6])

Enter number: 25
Reticulating Splines...
(25, 'is not a prime because of these factors', [1,5])
```

Poor control structure is my guess, but can someone fix my code?

I understand how range() works: In this case range() is given a start and a stop value, step defaults to 1. I understand that continue, continues a loop, but can I use it with if? I think that is wrong.

**UPDATE**
Solved, problem with indentation <strike>the continue should have been for the for loop, ditto</strike> for the if...notprime.

```
def isprime(number):
    print "Reticulating Splines..."
    fnum=[1,]
    notprime=0
    for p in range(2, number):
        if (number % p) == 0:
            notprime=1
            fnum.append(p)
    if notprime == 1:     
        return number, "is not a prime because of these factors", fnum  
    else:
        return number, "is a prime number"
num =int(raw_input("Enter number: "))
print isprime(num)
```

**Update2:**  (Thx to @neil)
And the `continue` is plain stupid

**Updated Code and speed comparisons between n/2 and sqrt(n)**
Thanks to @neil and @emmanuel
**n/2 code: v2**

```
import time
def isprime(number):
    start=time.clock()
    print "Reticulating Splines..."
    fnum=[1,]
    notprime=0
    for p in range(2, (number/2)+1):
        if (number % p) == 0:
            notprime=1
            fnum.append(p)
    end=time.clock()
    if notprime == 1:     
        return number, "is not a prime because of these factors", fnum, "Time taken", end-start  
    else:
        return number, "is a prime number. Time Taken", end-start
print "Prime or factor calculator v2 using n/2"
print #
num =int(raw_input("Enter number: "))
print isprime(num)
```

**sqrt(n) code: v3**

```
import math, time
def isprime(number):
    start=time.clock()
    print "Reticulating Splines..."
    fnum = [1,]
    last = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(number)))
    for p in range(2, last + 1):
        if (number % p) == 0:
            fnum.append(p)
            fnum.append(number / p)
    # Remove duplicates, sort list
    fnum = list(set(fnum))
    fnum.sort()
    end=time.clock()
    if len(fnum) > 1:     
        return number, "is not a prime because of these factors", fnum ,"Time taken", end-start 
    else:
        return True, "Time taken", end-start

print "Prime or factor calculator v3 using sqrt(n)"
print #

num =int(raw_input("Enter number: "))

print isprime(num)
```

**Output(Showing only time)**

**Time for sqrt(n) code: v3**
Prime or factor calculator v3 using sqrt(n)
Enter number: 999999
Time taken', **0.0022617399697466567**

**Time for n/2 code: v2**
Prime or factor calculator v2 using n/2
Enter number: 999999
Time taken: **0.11294955085074321**

**Time for original code(n): v1**
Prime or factor calculator v1
Enter number: 999999
Time taken: **0.22059172324972565**

v1 and v2 could not handle numbers 999999999, 999999999999 and 999999999999999, both gave a **MemoryError**

However v3 handled the three numbers:
999999999       : 0.010536255306192288
999999999999    : 0.75631930873896636
999999999999999 : 24.04511104064909

The shell hangs for 9999999999999999 and gives a MemoryError for 999999999999999999

Thanks to @Lennart, I am thinking of rewriting the code in a more OOP friendly way, by using classes. But I don't seem to be doing it right.

Comment: Subject: "Calculate all possible factors of a prime". Suppose the prime is *p*, then the factors and 1 and *p*.

Comment: @David should I change the subject?

Comment: @abel It might help, but I guess the question explains it. I just thought it was funny - finding the factors of a prime is pretty easy!!

Comment: @David There is always a first time!

Comment: You might enjoy using True and False instead of 1 and 0.

Comment: @Fred Takes longer to type and I am always unsure about capitalization. Are there any benefits using boolean instead of 0 or 1?

Comment: Clarity of code.  You should not be worrying about typing speed at your stage.

Comment: @Fred Thx. I should be using boolean.

Comment: And, by the way, I didn't mean you will later be much more concerned with typing speed either: code clarity is always more important.  (Though with experience, the breadth of code that "becomes" clear is larger.)  Particularly when you're learning basic concepts, typing itself should be much less important.

Comment: @abel If you spend more time writing code than reading code, then you are doing it wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your indentation - `if notprime==1:` shouldn't be within the for loop.  It should only have one level of indentation.

Also, the `continue` is unnecessary.

EDIT:

An improvement you can make (I was just working on primes last night for a Project Euler problem) is to only loop to n/2 - there can't be a factor greater than half the number.

Comment: Is there a way to convert it into a lambda function? I implemented n/2 by changing ` for p in range(2, number):` to  `for p in range(2, (number/2)+1):`

Answer (score 1):

Your final `if notprime ...` and the three lines following it are indented too far and as such is executed inside the loop, instead of outside.

Answer (score 1):

You return after testing only one number. Move the if tests and the returns to outside of the for loop.

Also, returning `True` if it is a prime, and a string if it is not is unpractical.
If you then call

```
if isprime(7):
```

That will always evaluate as True. I've improved things a bit:

```
def factors(number):
    fnum=[]
    for p in range(2, number):
        if (number % p) == 0:
            fnum.append(p)
    return fnum

for x in range(100):
    f = factors(x)
    if f:
        print x, "is not a prime and has factors", f
    else:
        print x, "is a prime"
```

Answer (score 1):

@neil:

> "An improvement you can make ... is to only loop to n/2 - there can't be a factor greater than half the number."

By the way, the highest value you need to test is `int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)))`, no need to go to `n/2` if each time you get a value, you get the associated one (i.e. if `a x b = n`, either `a` or `b` is lower than the square root of n and the other one is greater):

```
def isprime(number):
    print "Reticulating Splines..."
    fnum = [1,]
    last = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(number)))
    for p in range(2, last + 1):
        if (number % p) == 0:
            fnum.append(p)
            fnum.append(number / p)
    # Remove duplicates, sort list
    fnum = list(set(fnum))
    fnum.sort()
    if len(fnum) > 1:     
        return number, "is not a prime because of these factors", fnum  
    else:
        return True
```

Greater performance, even if at the end the list is not sorted (but this can be done inside the loop by adding the 2 numbers `p` and `number / p` at the good indexes).

Comment: posted comparison between using your method vs n/2