# Access a method's local variables in Python

Tags: python, oop

Was going through a Python Tutorial and have asked a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781841/calculate-all-possible-factors-of-a-prime)(Code from my previous example and thanks to @emmanuel)

**Code:**

```
import math, time
class PrimeFactor:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def isprime(self,number):
        start=time.clock()
        fnum = [1,]
        print "Reticulating Splines..."
        last = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(number)))
        for p in range(2, last + 1):
            if (number % p) == 0:
                fnum.append(p)
                fnum.append(number / p)
        # Remove duplicates, sort list
        fnum = list(set(fnum))
        fnum.sort()
        end=time.clock()
        if len(fnum) > 1:
            return number, "is not a prime because of these factors", fnum ,"Time taken", end-start
        else:
            return True, "Time taken", end-start

print "Prime or factor calculator v3 using sqrt(n)"
print #

num =int(raw_input("Enter number: "))
eg=PrimeFactor()

print eg.isprime(num)
```

From this code, I tried to get the variable fnum which is local to the function(method) isprime, which contains the factor list. Accessing it by calling

```
print eg.isprime(num).fnum
```

gave me a error

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fnum'
```

I guess I cannot call a local variable that way.

Plus the code is not reusable. So I decided to do a rewrite, to make it more modular.

**Rewritten Code:**

```
import math
class PrimeFactor:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def isPrime(self,number):
        fnum = [1,]
        last = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(number)))
        for p in range(2, last + 1):
            if (number % p) == 0:
                return False
            else:
                return True
    def getFactors(self,number):
        fnum = [1,]
        last = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(number)))
        for p in range(2, last + 1):
            if (number % p) == 0:
                fnum.append(p)
                fnum.append(number / p)
        # Remove duplicates, sort list
        fnum = list(set(fnum))
        fnum.sort()
        if len(fnum) > 1:
            return fnum
        else:
            return None


num =int(raw_input("Enter number: "))
eg=PrimeFactor()

if eg.isPrime(num):
    print num, "is a Prime Number"
else:
    print num, "is not a prime number"
    print "Factors", eg.getFactors(num)
```

I had to forgo time calculation. I can calculate time while using an instance.

**Question:**

Can I access the local variable `fnum` in my previous example? If yes, How?(I guess no). If no, then is the rewritten code good enough or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: After the function returns, its local variables are gone.  Everything that might be used by the caller should be returned to the caller.

Comment: @Sven So I could ask it to return a dict instead, with the first dict entry being a bool carrying whether the number is a prime, followed by a second item which will contain the factor list. That will save some time. I could then do away with the extra method

Comment: Just return a tuple, but without those strings.  And while you are at it, also trash your class and use simple functions.  Your class does not do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your modification is that you're duplicating the calculus. I understand you just want to get the calculated factors, which just involves creating fnum as an attribute:

```
import math, time
class PrimeFactor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fnum = [1,]
        self.elapsedTime = 0
    def getElapsedTime(self):
        return self.elapsedTime
    def getFactors(self):
        return self.fnum
    def isprime(self,number):
        start=time.clock()
        self.fnum = [1,]
        last = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(number)))
        for p in range(2, last + 1):
            if (number % p) == 0:
                self.fnum.append(p)
                self.fnum.append(number / p)
        # Remove duplicates, sort list
        self.fnum = list(set(self.fnum))
        self.fnum.sort()
        end=time.clock()
        self.elapsedTime = end-start
        return (not len(self.fnum) > 1 )

num =int(raw_input("Enter number: "))
eg=PrimeFactor()

if eg.isprime(num):
    print num, "is a Prime Number", eg.isprime(num)
else:
    print num, "is not a prime number"
    print "Factors", eg.getFactors()
print eg.getElapsedTime()
```

You could even develop the code a little bit more and take advantage of the previous calculated factors, thus using dynamic programming.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That means, if I call PrimeFactor.getFactors(), isprime will still be executed? I am a OOP noob.

Comment: Nope, but you can easily solve that, if you're interested. You just have to prepend to self.getFactors(): if ( self.fnum < 2 ): self.isPrime( 101 )

Comment: I have edited your code for some typos. I didn't know how to create attributes.

Comment: @abel, that's fine. About attributes, Python is a little bit different to other programming languages. As you can see, you just create them by assigning them a value inside the constructor __init__

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
print eg.isprime(num)[2]
```

(your method is returning a tuple, and you need the third member, that's all)

Comment: I agree. The return is a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to access the local variables of a function from outside that function.  You need to explicitly make them available to callers, either by returning them, or by writing their values into a container available to the caller.

Comment: the OP is indeed returning the variables s/he wants in the first example - s/he's just trying to access them the wrong way

Comment: @simon - Your answer is correct but needs to have Ned's explanation to make it clear why the OP is nots eeing what he expects